# the arrays program

Tags: java, arrays

Can someone please help me. I'm having a hard time on fixing the logic of my codes. this program is supposed to compute the average of a numbers entered by the user assuming that the size of the array is set to 100 and if User enters -99, program will be terminated
i know the problem is within the while loop processing

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] num = new int[100];

    int ctr=0, sum=0, ave = 0;

    while(num[ctr]!= -99)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        num[ctr]= input.nextInt();

        sum += num[ctr];

        ctr++;

    }

    System.out.print("Numbers are " );

    for(int x = 0; x<ctr; x++)
    {
        System.out.print(num[x] + " ");
    }

    ave = sum / (ctr-1);
    System.out.println("Average is " + ave);

    }

}
```

Comment: You should read the first input outside the `while` loop. Because when the user enters `-99`, inside the loop you increment `ctr` so the check will be on the wrong number.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that? i really have no idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the first input *outside* the while `while` loop. Because when the user enters `-99`, inside the loop you increment `ctr` so the check will be on the wrong number. So actually you are never checking the current number you wanted to check.

```
int ctr=0, sum=0, ave = 0;
System.out.print("Enter number: ");
num[ctr]= input.nextInt();
while(num[ctr]!= -99)
{
   sum += num[ctr];
   ctr++;
   System.out.print("Enter number: ");
   num[ctr]= input.nextInt();
}
```

But you need to handle the case which the user only enters one number, in this case you're dividing by zero, and you're getting the wrong average. You should also do:

```
ave = sum / (ctr);
```

instead of:

```
ave = sum / (ctr-1);
```

Now you'll get good results.

Comment: Thank you man! It's now working. I'm a freshman IT student btw. I'm a starter in java. I have a question, is that similar to a priming input? thanks

Comment: I'm glad it helped :) I don't understand what you mean, can you explain your question please?

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop does not have a termination condition for the case when the array is filled. (When 100 integers have been entered, and ctr is equal to 100.)

Comment: Thank you man. I have tried simulating it and yeah you're right

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `while` loop is that it never looks at the element that's just been entred; it always looks at the element right after it.